# Python - AttributeError: 'OnDemand' object has no attribute 'calc'

Tags: python, class, error-handling

Something is really happening and i couldnt resolve for a day almost

Examples are below: Trying a simple method calling from one class to another class to figure out the problem as i have experienced the notorious problem this morning as well... so have tried a simple method calling checks...
Two Class:
HomePageAlone 
OnDemand

HomePageAlone - defined a test "def test_E_Access(self):" calls method in OnDemand i got the below error.

Code as follows:

### HomePageAlone

```
from sikuli import *
from OnDemand import *
import OnDemand

class homePage(unittest.TestCase):

 def setUp(self):
  print("Test")   


 def test_E_Access(self):
  callMethod = OnDemand()
  callMethod.calc() # Line#15


suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(homePage('test_E_Access'))
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

### OnDemand

```
from sikuli import *

class OnDemand(object):

    def setUp(self):
        print("setup")


    def calc(self):
        print ("This is calling")
```

---

Log Message

======================================================================

### ERROR: test_E_Access (**main**.homePage)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\DOCUME~1\Senthil.S\LOCALS~1\Temp\sikuli-6018543662740221054.py", line 15, in test_E_Access
callMethod.calc(self) # Line#15
AttributeError: 'OnDemand' object has no attribute 'calc'

---

Ran 1 test in 0.016s

FAILED (errors=1)

Another Try : i tried to use as the below snippet as your suggested - it always throws AttributeError: 'OnDemandPopular' object has no attribute 'calc'

import OnDemandPopular
ondemand = OnDemandPopular.OnDemandPopular()
ondemand.calc()

Please help

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import **OnDemand** class from **OnDemand** module;

```
from OnDemand import OnDemand
```

**HomePageAlone**

```
import unittest
from OnDemand import OnDemand

class homePage(unittest.TestCase):

 def setUp(self):
  print("Test")   

 def test_E_Access(self):
  callMethod = OnDemand()
  callMethod.calc() # Line#15


suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(homePage('test_E_Access'))
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

**OnDemand**

```
class OnDemand(object):

    def setUp(self):
        print("setup")

    def calc(self):
        print ("This is calling")
```

The Output is ;

```
This is calling
test_E_Access (HomePageAlone.homePage) ... ok

Test
This is calling
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Test
This is calling
```

Comment: What is the difference between Module and class? Class has methods and trying to access a method on the class by importing and defining an object. Do you mean a module can have multiple classes?? Please help.

Comment: In essence; Module includes classes, you must google it!

Comment: And also, if the answer is true you should close the question; click to set this answer as your accepted answer.